# How to merge two images using second as a transparent binary mask in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, image-processing

For example I have a image of a cat, and second image with a mask of cat. And I want to add transparent red mask for pixels of a cat in first image.
Both images are numpy arrays...So how to do it?

Comment: Is the first image a 2D array or a 3D (color img)?

Comment: @Divakar, grayscale or RGB, let's assume 3 channels(rgb).

Answer (score 2):

IIUC you could do something like this -

```
img[:,:,2] = np.where(mask,255,img[:,:,2])
```

Results -

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, thought about it too... But hoped for alpha-channel images, i.e. not destroying R or other channel information.

Comment: @Il'yaZhenin Well sorry, don't have a solution for that.

Comment: @Il'yaZhenin even if you use an alpha channel, you will end up in altering the the original BGR channels. Are you trying to get some kind of layers? However, instead of overwriting the R channel completeley, the right approach might be to create a red (0,0,255) mask and blend it to your original image, for example with cv2.addWeighted or both images with factors 0.5 and 0.5